# Android http request POST

Tags: java, android, http, post, request

I'm building a simple android application that sends a http post request to this site http://www.ap-ljubljana.si/vozni_red2/VR2.php and then gets the apropriate response based on the post request. The problem is that my app doesn't get the same response as the browser. Any ideas why?

java file

```
`HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.ap-ljubljana.si/vozni_red2/VR3.php");

    try{

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VSTOP_ID", "1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IZSTOP_ID","1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("btnNext", "Naprej"));

        httppost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        httppost.setHeader("Origin", "http://www.ap-ljubljana.si");
        httppost.setHeader("Referer", "http://www.ap-ljubljana.si/vozni_red2/VR2.php?DATUM="+datum+"&VSTOP_IME=Vstop...&IZSTOP_IME=Izstop...");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        httppost.setHeader("DNT", "1");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "sl-SI,sl;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
        //httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));

        return httpclient.execute(httppost);

    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e){

        return null;
    }
    catch (IOException e){

        return null;
    }`
```

Browser's http post request

http://i45.tinypic.com/zvqww7.jpg

Comment: my app's http post request

http://i45.tinypic.com/2poqh4y.jpg

Comment: Please make sure you perform this connection on a separate thread... not on the UI thread.

Comment: yes i know i have to use multithreading but thats not the problem since im getting a response right? how can i use the cookies?

Comment: The point is that my apps request only works if I have this site already opened in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

There is cookie information is missing from your APP request.May be that is creating issues.Some server side debugging can resolve this issue, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not hitting the exact URL as the URLs you are hitting are not APIs, 
AFAIT, 
cause this is webpage URL pointing to it.

In browser when you do there are other API links which are performing tasks and you get correct response as webpages are built like that to help you to know response result, but when you do on this link its actually returning content of the above mentioned php links, while the main working is done by other API links.

Please let me know if I am wrong, so I may help you out.

Comment: yes I think the apropriate URL should be as the one in Referer, but im not gettng any response at all if I use that one.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's the one you need to pass. Also, make sure you need to pass all these values in your request according to the API documentation you received not more not less, which may turn out to be a null response. Try using your current Referer URL for main URL and replace your ORIGIN and REFERER with this one: "http : // www.ap-ljubljana.si /"(remove spaces) and confirm the result.

Comment: I did what you said and I actually thought it's working (it only works if I open the page I am expecting to get in my browser and then send the post through the app). Otherwise I get the wrong response again.

http://i47.tinypic.com/ws4s5w.jpg